# Add Separator In Collapsed Nav Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add a separator in the collapsed nav when viewed on mobile. Ideally the nav would look exactly the same as it does not when not collapsed, but when collapsed would have a separator between "About" and "Log In".

Here is the code for the nav:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-navbar" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Company</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-navbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ccnptfL/)

I have tried adding `<li role="separator" class="divider"></li>` where I want the separator, but it does not show up:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-navbar" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Company</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-navbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0f15341b/)

How can I add a separator for the collapsed nav?

This separator would hopefully look very similar to that of a dropdown in a nav:

[image: screenshot from Bootstrap website showing separator]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It does not show up as It is defined as follows in Bootstrap css:

```
.dropdown-menu .divider {
    height: 1px;
    margin: 9px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
```

And you do not have `.divider` under `.dropdown-menu`

What you should do ?

```
@media (max-width:767px){
  .divider {
        height: 1px;
        margin: 9px 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #e5e5e5;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Rather than keep it in the `<ul>` I made a `<div>` outside with the class `.collapsed-divider` and modifying the margin line to `margin: 9px -15px;`. Works perfectly!

Answer (score 18):

In Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.6, you can use

```
<div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Abava/y6z3buk2/)

Answer (score 5):

You have to put this code:

> `<li role="separator" class="divider"></li>`

between your own "< li >" tags.

Example:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="drop2">
  <li> Your own Li Tags</li>
  <li> Your own Li Tags</li>
  <li> Your own Li Tags</li>
  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
  <li> Your own Li Tags</li>
  <li> Your own Li Tags</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

### Boostrap 4.1 Solution

Was trying to accomplish this in a BS4.1 Navbar component and ended up here (via Google). Since `.divider` does not exist in this version, I used `<hr>` to achieve the desired result...

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="https://www.sociallinkgenerator.com/#generator">Social Links</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="https://www.sociallinkgenerator.com/facebook-link-generator/#opengraph-generator">Open Graph</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="https://www.sociallinkgenerator.com/twitter-link-generator/#twitter-card-generator">Twitter Cards</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/json-ld-generator#json-ld-generator">JSON-LD</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><hr class="border-top"></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="https://www.sociallinkgenerator.com/#donation">Feeling Generous?</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="https://www.sociallinkgenerator.com/#contact">Need a Developer?</a></li>
</ul>
```

Bonus: This `<hr>` did not affect expanded display since its margins place it behind the next `.nav-item` element :)

Note: `.border-top` was added to the `<hr>` for lighter color.

Comment: Excellent, a clean solution

Answer (score 1):

you may insert an

```
<hr>
```

Tag instead of your divider [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/43wsmyvd/):

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <hr>            
        <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Please tell me if it is as you wanted.

Comment: I tried this solution but it looks strange when the page is rendered. better try this way between Ul,Li tags:      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>

Comment: Note: `<ul>` spec only allows `<li>` children. If you try this, remember to wrap the horizontal rule. Example: `<li><hr></li>`

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul

Comment: If you find extra margins, use `<hr class="m-0">`

Answer (score 0):

In **Bootstrap 5** you can add it as list item with css class `dropdown-divider` like so:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Your dropdown name
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item 1<a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item 2<a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -2):

If you don't want to touch css there is little hack for it :D.
Instead of

```
<li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
```

use this

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" style="padding:0px; border-top-width:0px;"></form>
```

Bootstrap gives forms 1px borders on top and bottom when collapsed. You can use this and insert empty form which is invisible while expanded but with one border while collapsed.